# I want to remove brackets from text before hyphen only in php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this string:

```
(3330) - PATRIOT SPRAYER (11/08-)
```

And I want to remove brackets only from `3330`. Expected output:

```
3330 - PATRIOT SPRAYER (11/08-)
```

I have tried to use:

```
$pattern =  ('/[[(.)]]/')
```

But I don't get my expected result. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hH5vW4/1).

Comment: For what reason you only want to remove brackets around 3330? Because they are the first in the string, because 3330 is a number, because...

Comment: You went wrong when you did not specify the requirements for the task. When the requirements are not clear, any answer is good and bad at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `^` to mark the start of the line. This would give you an regex like the following:

```
^\(([^)]+)\)
```

and the with php `preg_replace`

```
$line = preg_replace('~^\(([^)]+)\)~', '$1', $line);
```

Comment: Note that in this case, the parentheses round `(LETTERS_&chars-other-than-closing-round bracket)` will also be removed.

Comment: @stribizhev I dont know, what you mean? My expression search the `(anything expect ')' at the start of the line)` and replace it with everything inside the parentheses - thats the same as your expression, expect in my version you could also write other chars inside

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$str = '(3330) - PATRIOT SPRAYER (11/08-)';
$str = preg_replace('/\(([^)]+)\)(\s*-)/', "$1$2", $str);
```